# Access django url without apache http basic authentication

Tags: django, apache, http, http-redirect, apache2.4

I'm working on a Django 3.2 project which is hosted using Apache 2.4 server. The user authentication in this project is handled using HTTP Basic Authentication configured using LDAP.

I have implemented a sign up feature for new users. For that I have created the necessary form, view, template and url pattern in the Django project. The urlpattern to visit the sign up form is `/signup`.

My goal is to make the sign up urlpattern accessible to anyone i.e. prevent the Basic Authentication from showing when the sign up urlpattern is requested by user in the browser.

JFI, the complete Apache configuration is already complete and works already.

To achieve this, I have used the "LocationMatch" directive in the Apache configuration within the `VirtualHost` directive:

```
...
<LocationMatch "^/signup$">
    Require all granted
</LocationMatch> 
...
```

With this the Basic Authentication is removed when `/signup` URI is requested, but the server always **redirects** to another url which ultimately requires authentication hence giving the basic auth pop-up.

```
$ curl -I https://*****.com/signup
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
```

I have tried to redirect the request explicitly to `/signup` whenever the is `/signup`. This ends up in an endless loop of redirections.

```
RewriteEngine on
...
RewriteRule ^/signup$ /signup [R=301,L]
```

I have also tried other ways by setting environment variables within Apache configuration, I have restarted Apache whenever a change was done in config, I have cleared browser cache etc., but nothing seems be working.

**FYI, I can access the `/signup` url successfully after logging into the application which is not useful for me.**

I'm afraid I cannot share the complete source (apache config, django source etc.) here as the project is not completely open source yet. But I'm sure your suggestions would surely help me in some way.

**I want to fix the redirection.** I have no clue what I'm missing out here.

Comment: It would seem the redirect is coming from somewhere that possibly isn't apache itself if there's nothing else in any .htaccess files.  Maybe the signup view?  There's no @login_required decorator for it?  If not, check through the codebase looking for references to the page it redirects to (I assume that's always the same page)

Comment: @SamSparx thanks for the suggestions. You were right, Apache wasn't causing the redirection. I had to dig into the django project source code only to find a custom middleware causing the redirection every time. After making few changes to the custom middleware, I could achieve the result I wanted! :-)